# Telerik Skin Change Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, telerik, themes, skin

I need to change entire web Application Skin Dynamically when User Changes a Theme from RadSkinManager Drop Down menu. Below Code changes the Page Theme but doesn't Change the entire Application skin. How can I achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

RadSkinManager will change the skin of all the Telerik controls in the current page (including master/content pages and user controls) if they do not have an explicit setting for their Skin property.

Perhaps you should look into storing the desired skin somewhere (file, database, whatever) and simply set the SkinManager's Skin to the desired value (e.g., in Page_Init).